# How to perform string.replace for "\\\\" to " \\"

Tags: c#, string, replace

While working on a code i need to replace "\\" with "\", I tried many solutions but none of them worked,

Here is what i tried

```
string a1 = "ABC\\NameHere";
string b1 = a1.Replace("\\\\","\\");
string c1 = a1.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

but nothing gave me desired output, Can any one help

Comment: Try `@"\\\\"` and `@"\\"` - the backslashes are escaping the next character but with @ they don't escape so you need all 4 etc - do you want to replace two backslashes or 1?

Comment: Actually, your string does not have \\ character. It _just_ have \ character. You can see it on debugger.

Comment: Yeah don't forget in the debugger you will see ESCAPED strings - so you will see extra backslashes escaping other characters. Is this a DOMAIN\USERNAME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct; the problem is that `a1` only has one slash in it.  Try this:

```
    string a1 = @"ABC\\NameHere";
    string b1 = a1.Replace("\\\\","\\");
    string c1 = a1.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: it is giving this output "ABC\\\\NameHere"

Comment: How are you producing that output?  Like Charleh says in the comments, the debugger will show the full escape sequence.